# Unwind of custom segue not triggered

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue, unwind-segue

**Problem**

My problem is that unwind process is not triggered even though back button is clicked.

**My code**

I have a class 1stViewController that uses a custom segue to 2ndViewController. The custom segue is the following:

```
override func perform() {
    let sourceVC = self.source as! 1stViewController
    let destinationVC = self.destination as! 2ndViewController
    sourceVC.addChildViewController(destinationVC)
    sourceVC.view.addSubview(destinationVC.view)
}
```

In my 2ndViewController I have added a button that triggers an unwinding segue back to 1stViewController. The unwinding segue is connected through the identifier of the unwind segue triggering exit in the 2ndViewController. Thus, I have created an IBAction that the unwind segue exit is connected to:

```
@IBAction func unwindToFeed(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
```

I have set the identifier of the unwind segue equal to the one used in the action function of the button

```
func handleActionBackButton(){
    print("here")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindId", sender: self)
}
```

"Here" is printed when button is clicked, but it seems like performSegue is not.

I guessed that I needed a custom unwindSegue class as well, so I created  unwindSegueEventToFeed:

```
class unwindSegueEventToFeed: UIStoryboardSegue {

override func perform() {
    let sourceVC = self.source as! 2ndViewController
    let destinationVC = self.destination as! 1stViewController

    let sourceView = sourceVC.view as UIView!
    let destView = destinationVC.view as UIView!

    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    window?.insertSubview(destView!, aboveSubview: sourceView!)
    sourceVC.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

}
...which is called in the 2ndViewController:

```
override func segueForUnwinding(to toViewController: UIViewController, from fromViewController: UIViewController, identifier: String?) -> UIStoryboardSegue? {
    return unwindSegueEventToFeed(identifier: identifier, source: fromViewController, destination: toViewController)
}
```

Any clues on what I have to do different to trigger the unwinding process?

Comment: Just to confirm, `unwindToFeed` is in 1stViewController ?

Comment: The unwindToFeed is in the 2ndViewController

Comment: That's the wrong place. The unwind method goes in the view controller you are unwinding *to*

Comment: But shouldn't the unwindToFeed be in the view that you want to dismiss? 2ndViewController is the view visible to the user where the button is located

Comment: No. you can unwind to a VC from any number of VCs so the unwind action method gives you a consistent place to process the unwind. You don't need an unwind method in the source since you can have a simple button action handler or even trigger the unwind directly from a UI element without code. Apple has a good tech note on using unwind segues

Comment: Thanks man, working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your example to work like this. ViewController is the first view controller; ViewController2 is the second view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func unwindToFeed(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        let child = self.childViewControllers[0]
        child.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        child.view.removeFromSuperview()
        child.removeFromParentViewController()
    }
}

class MySegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        let sourceVC = self.source as! ViewController
        let destinationVC = self.destination as! ViewController2
        sourceVC.addChildViewController(destinationVC)
        sourceVC.view.addSubview(destinationVC.view)
        destinationVC.view.frame = sourceVC.view.bounds
        destinationVC.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        destinationVC.didMove(toParentViewController: sourceVC)
    }
}

class ViewController2 : UIViewController {
}
```

Note that `unwindToFeed` is (and must be) in the *first* view controller. It is meaningless to put it in the second view controller, as the second view controller is the *source*, not the *destination*, of the unwind.

Now I'd like to make some comments about the problem and my answer:

- This is an iOS 10 example. `segueForUnwinding` will *never* be called in iOS 10; it was abandoned after iOS 8 and was subsequently deprecated.
- The iOS 9/10 equivalent of `segueForUnwinding` is `unwind(for:towardsViewController:)`. I did try implementing it, but I found that it was called in ViewController2, not in ViewController. I regard that as a bug in iOS 10, and am reporting it to Apple.

Comment: But my example doesn't work at all in iOS 9. In general the whole notion of using unwind segues with a custom parent view controller still looks very broken, as it has been for years, and I would suggest avoiding it entirely.